# Cycle through an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of the form [1,2,3,4,5].

Is it possible to loop through this array and during each iteration get an array where the starting point is the current element and the end point is the element before that?

Like

```
[1,2,3,4,5]

[2,3,4,5,1]

[3,4,5,1,2]

[4,5,1,2,3]

[5,1,2,3,4]
```

I am trying with .cycle method of array but it is not giving the expected result.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [rotate](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate).

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.rotate         #=> ["b", "c", "d", "a"]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
irb(main):005:0> array = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):006:0> array.size.times.map{|i| array.rotate(i)}
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 1], [3, 4, 5, 1, 2], [4, 5, 1, 2, 3], [5, 1, 2 , 3, 4]]
```